# Content not showing properly with the first load of the page

Tags: templates

As i am building my website with Elementor, i noticed that certain pages (almost all of them) are showing the first time not quite properly. For example, I set a black background for a section and some padding for paragraphs that are not showing the first time you enter a page. Only after you reload the page, they appear. I set all the pages template to 'default' and inside Elementor i used the 'boxed' option for the sections. There is also one other page that when loaded doesn't appear some padding at the top. Can you please assist?
Thanks!

Best,
Mira

Comment: This could be something else throwing an error or perhaps some caching if you're actively working on the site?  Ultimately this question would best be posed to the developers of Elementor.

Comment: I am working on the site, but i already tried many things. I tried many times regenerating the files on Elementor and it doesn't work